# need help " server sent disconnect message type 11 (by application) "User authentication timeout""

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine

i am learning sql server now. appreciate any help to solve this problem.
create a win server 2016 virtual machine (VMWare). and install bitvise ssh server in the win2016. however, when i try to use   putty to connect to win2016. it got the message like this. "server sent disconnect message type 11 (by application) "User authentication timeout""

this is from putty 
"login as: administrator
SSH server: Password authentication
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:
Access denied
SSH server: Password authentication
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
"
and the fig is from sshserver log.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlpSL.jpg)